# How to turn off submodule of a C++ library based on preprocessor defined macro

Tags: c++, cmake, macros, c-preprocessor

**What I'm doing** I'm writing a C++ library with dependence on `NetCDF` library. For example,

```
include <netcdf>
class myLib {
    public:

        myLib();
        myLib(const myLib&);
        virtual ~myLib();

        std::string probe_data(std::string & file_path);
        ...
```

And the function `probe_data` uses the functions from `NetCDF` library.

**What is the problem** I have defined a preprocessor macro `CANALOGSIO_WITHOUT_NETCDF`. Because in some system, there is no `NetCDF` library installed. So I would like to turn off this functionality in my library, for example, the library will still have `probe_data` function, but it simply returns `NetCDF not installed`.

What would be a good practice of doing that? Thank you!

Comment: How about `#ifdef NETCDF do probe  #endif`   then `cc -DNETCDF`

Comment: Thank you for your input. In this way, if `NETCDF` is not defined, there would be no `probe_data` function. However, if some other program calls this function, it would give an error. I would like to still have this function when no `NETCDF` is present, but it simply prints out a warning message.

Comment: There are surely better solutions, but you could create two header-only libraries, one with the functions that rely on netCDF and one that only prints warnings. You can then use the suggested construct to compile with the one or with the other.

Comment: `#ifdef NETCFG do probe #else print messag #endif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll list 2 different methods which came to my mind for this.

1, just use ifdefs in the definition of the function. This will keep the uniform interface and everyone could call it.

```
class myLib {

    ...
    std::string probe_data(std::string & file_path) {
       #ifdef NETCDF
         return do_real_probe(file_pat);
       #else
         cerr << "NOt implemented function" << endl;
         return "";
       #endif
     }

    ...
```

This requires separate compilation for separate systems. YOu need to supply the definition of the macro at the compilation comand line, i.e. with gcc:

```
g++ -DNETCDF ..
```

2. the second method wold be based on the library approach. You can compile separate implementation libraries for different systems. Then at link time you can choose which static library to use (or at run time for dynamic libs). Most likely you would only deliver the library which work on the target system and nothing will. You might get away without #ifdefs if you choose so, just have different implementation in different files>

sys1.cpp

```
 string probe(string &) { return do_probe();}
 gcc sys1.cpp -o sys1.so -shared
```

sys2.cpp

```
 string probe(string &) {cerr << messate; return "";}
 gcc sys2.cpp -o sys2.so -shared
```

Now you just need to deliver the correct library (sys1 or sys2) to the correct system. Or a correct statically linked image of your program.

There are multiple way to use conditional compilation to do it. So you decide.

Comment: A follow up question on that. In you second solution, if some functions in my library takes a parameter of a netcdf type, what do I do to this function declaration when there is no netcdf in the system? Thank you.

Comment: if this is a pointer or a reference type, you can get away with a forward declaration in a common header file, just add `class netcdf;` there. However if you pass it as value, or use its members in other parts of your program, this would become ugly and will require ifdefs and multiple declarations of the class. So, use references of pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comments entirely. Even if I use the members or pass as values, if they won't be used elsewhere, I can still make a forward declaration for them, right? Thank you.

Comment: if you pass a struct as a value, you need to fully define it somewhere in the code. If you pass it as a pointer,  and do **not** use its members in he function, you do not have to define the strcuct, just define a `pointer to the struct`, So, if your dummy implementation of the function does not reference any member of the struct/class, the "forward" declaration is sufficient to define a `pointer type` to it. `struct mystruct; void myfunction(mystruct *){do something here}`